# RR MILLENNIUM equivalent in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Is there a built in function in PostgreSQL 9.5 version to calculate the appropriate century/millenium?

When I use birth_date::TIMESTAMP from a table, sometimes it prefix 19 and sometimes it prefix 20. Below example

Input:

```
28JUN80  
25APR48
```

Output:

```
"1980-06-28 00:00:00"  
"2048-04-25 00:00:00"
```

I also have records in the table with birth_date holding values like "07APR1963" which gets computed appropriately as "1963-04-07 00:00:00".

I need use CASE statement when the length is 7 characters, then prefix with 19 millennium and when its 9 characters, just load it as it is.

Comment: to_timestamp(birth_date,'DDMONYYYY') gives me a value like   "0080-06-28 00:00:00+00" and   "0048-04-25 00:00:00+00"

Comment: Can you please try this? select to_timestamp('25APR48', 'ddmonyy'). For me, the resultset is "2048-04-25 00:00:00+00". I was expecting it to be starting as 1948

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time **Unix epoch is**

> **beginning (00:00:00 1 January 1970)**

So if you don't specify the century, but just last `YY` it will be 20th century from `00:00:00 1 January` and 21st century before `YY` equal `70`. If you want it to guess the 20th century either append year as you do, or specify `CC`, eg:

```
t=> select 
  to_timestamp('1JAN70', 'ddmonYY')
, to_timestamp('31DEC69', 'ddmonyy')
, to_timestamp('31DEC69 20', 'ddmonyy cc');
      to_timestamp      |      to_timestamp      |      to_timestamp
------------------------+------------------------+------------------------
 1970-01-01 00:00:00+00 | 2069-12-31 00:00:00+00 | 1969-12-31 00:00:00+00
(1 row)
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html

> In conversions from string to timestamp or date, the CC (century)
>   field is ignored if there is a YYY, YYYY or Y,YYY field. If CC is used
>   with YY or Y then the year is computed as the year in the specified
>   century. If the century is specified but the year is not, the first
>   year of the century is assumed.

**update**

So in your case you should do smth like:

```
vao=# create table arasu (member_birth_date character(9)); insert into arasu values ('28JUN80'),('25APR48');
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 2
vao=# select to_timestamp(member_birth_date||' 20', 'ddmonYY cc') from arasu;
      to_timestamp
------------------------
 1980-06-28 00:00:00+03
 1948-04-25 00:00:00+03
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks Vao, to_timestamp('31DEC69 20', 'ddmonyy cc') seems to be good option for me. But I'm unable to perform this on a table column which holds the date in VARCHAR field    Ex: `select to_timestamp(to_date(birth_date, 'DDMONYYYY') ||''||19, 'ddmonyy cc')
from schema.table  a`

Comment: @HarinathArasu updtaed the answer with example of concatenation that did not work for you

Comment: ` create table schema.arasu (member_birth_date character(9))

insert into schema.arasu  values ('28JUN80')

select to_timestamp('20'||member_birth_date, 'ddmonyy cc') from schema.arasu  a`

Comment: Please try inserting with '25APR48' also, which is when the issue occurs

Comment: updated with your schema example - mind the space before century